# Uploading Image to Directory and Writing Image Name to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm trying upload an image to a directory and write the image name to my database; however, the filename is showing up null and I'm getting an **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error for the HttpPostedFileBase file variable when it is a parameter in the HttpPost Create() method in my controller.

**Here is the filename in the Model:**

```
public string ImageName { get; set; }
```

**This is the View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Expense</legend>
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Here is the HttpPost Create() method in the Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Create(Expense expense, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var fullName = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == expense.UserId).Select(n => n.FullName).ToArray()[0];

                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fullName), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }

                var query =
                    from e in db.Expenses
                    where e.ExpenseId == expense.ExpenseId
                    select e;

                foreach (Expense exp in query)
                {
                    exp.ImageName = file.FileName;
                }

                db.Expenses.Add(expense);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
            ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.UserProfiles, "UserId", "UserName", expense.UserId);
            return View(expense);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a local variable before you check/save the file, and setting the value of this to the `file.FileName`? Then you can reference this variable in your `foreach` loop

Comment: Hey @GeoffJames, I have tried doing that. I still get object reference error.

Comment: OK, so the `file` itself is `null`, if I understand right? Ensure in your form, that you have the file field's `name` _and_ `id` set to `file`, and set the form's `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and ensure that the method is `post`

Comment: @GeoffJames do you by chance know what's going wrong with the object reference error?

Comment: You need to set some things up in the `@Html.BeginForm` helper - you are missing the important bit `"enctype="multipart/form-data"` in order to pass files to the controller, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make sure that the `enctype` of the form is set to `"multipart/form-data"` in order for it to send files to the controller.

In your `@Html.BeginForm()` method, you need to pass some parameters:

```
@Html.BeginForm(action,
                controller,
                FormMethod.Post,
                new { enctype="multipart/form-data"}) // <-- Important for uploading files
```

Where `action` is the name of the action you're posting to (`"Create"`) in this case, and `controller` is the name of the controller that action is on (don't know it in your instance, but as an example `"ExpenseController"`).

Also, I like to ensure that the `id` and `name` attributes of the `<input ...` are both set.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
You can also pass `null` and `null` as your action and controller params for the `Html.BeginForm` method, like this:

```
@Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Geoff! :-)